# Limiting conditional probability measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

$(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a probability triple. Suppose $B_{i} \in \mathcal{F}$ with $P\left(B_{i}\right)>0$. Let $P_1(A) = P(A|B_1)$; define $P_{n}(A)=P_{n-1}\left(A \mid B_{n}\right)$. What is the probability measure $Q(A)=\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} P_{n}(A)$ for $A \in \mathcal{F}$? (What is the condition if the measure $Q$ exists?)

Based on my understanding, $\displaystyle P_n(A) = \frac{P(A \cap(\cap_{i=1}^n B_i))}{P(\cap_{i=1}^n B_i)}$. If $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a decreasing sequence, $B_n \downarrow B$, $B > 0$ according to the assumption, $P_n(A)$ is either 0 or 1. What about the more general situation? Does the limit exist when both numerator and denominator approach zero? Do we have something similar to L'Hospital's rule to calculate the limit?

**Edit** 
Not sure whether the following analysis is reasonable or not.
Let $C_k = \cap_{i=1}^k B_k$, $C_k$ is a decreasing sequence; suppose $C_n \downarrow C$, $C$ is nontrivial. 
if $A \cap C \neq \emptyset$, $Q(A) = \frac{P(A \cap C)}{P(C)}$;
if $A \cap C = \emptyset $, $Q(A) = 0$;

Answer (score 1):

The limiting probability is $P\left(A \mid C_{n}\right) \rightarrow P(A \mid C)$ if $P(C) \neq 0$.